# $T$ has an orthonormal eigenbasis when $T$ is the orthogonal projection onto a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $T$ is the orthogonal projection onto a subspace $V$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Show that $T$ has an orthonormal eigenbasis.

So I believe that $T$ has eigenvalues $0$ and $1$, since the condition $A\vec{x}=\lambda\vec{x}$ is only satisfied when $\vec{x}$ is perpendicular to $V$ ($0$) or in $V$ ($1$), but I don't know how I can prove that there will always be an orthonormal eigenbasis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose any orthonormal basis $\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\}$ you want for $V$.

Choose any orthonormal basis $\{w_1,\ldots,w_{n-k}\}$ you want for $V^{\perp}$.

Then each $v_i$ is a unit-length eigenvector for $T$ with eigenvalue $1$, and each $w_i$ is a unit-length eigenvector for $T$ with eigenvalue $0$, and every $v_i$ is orthogonal to every $w_j$ by definition of $V^{\perp}$.

Thus $\{v_1,\ldots,v_k,w_1,\ldots,w_{n-k}\}$ is an orthonormal eigenbasis for $T$.

Comment: Can you comment on if $T$ were a reflection about a subspace $V$? It seems like the analysis would be very similar, except each $w_i$ would have eigenvalue $-1$. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

first show that image of $T$ is the subspace $V$ and $Tv = v$ for all $v \in V.$

next show that null space of $T$ is the orthogonal complement of $V,$ that is all vectors orthogonal to every vector in $V.$

next show these two two spaces have only the null vector in common.

now pick a basis in $image(T)$ and $null(T)$ with respect to the projection $T$ is represented by a diagonal matrix of one's and zero's. the number of ones is the dimension of the subspace $V$ you started with.